# Container Access in Windows Azure Storage Resets to Private

Tags: windows, azure, storage, blob

We are new to `Windows Azure` though we have learnt good amount of things and are quite fast learners.
We have used `Windows Azure` storage for blob objects while developing sitefinity application but this storage access resets to private automatically after certain time period (30 mins or so) and then the pages where these images are accessed are stopped displaying.

Please check the file attached to see the screenshot.
Then we have to manually login into `Windows Azure` storage and set this to public blob or public container and then it start displaying.

Please help me to solve this. I think I am missing some settings for this.
[image: storage access screenshot]

Comment: Screenshot shows `wad-control-container`. Are you using this container to store blobs?

Comment: yes. i just updated access to public BLOB 30 mins back and now it is again private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wad-control-container` is a special container which holds `Windows Azure Diagnostics` configuration data. It is created and managed by diagnostics agent running in your VM and by default its ACL is `Private`. I believe what is happening is that diagnostics agent is periodically trying to create this container and at that time it is changing its ACL to `Private`. I would recommend using some other blob container for your application to store blobs.

Comment: thanks gaurav. seems like you are an expert in azure. Can you please answer the other questions which i asked today. It will be much appreciated. Pasting links of 4 questions in the next 4 messages.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040456/how-to-achieve-incremental-deployment-of-blob-files-storage-files-to-different-e

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039635/how-to-achieve-incremental-deployment-of-sitefinity-code-files-to-different-envi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038903/blob-files-have-to-renamed-manually-to-include-parent-folder-path

Comment: hey gaurav.can you please take a look at the question posted by me today.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409166/how-do-we-deploy-wcf-inside-any-asp-net-website-webproject-on-azure