# How to achieve Incremental deployment of Sitefinity Code Files to different environments of windows azure?

Tags: windows, azure, storage, blob, sitefinity

We are new to Windows azure and are developing a Sitefinity web application. In the beginning of the project , we have deployed complete code using Sitefinity Thunder to different environments which actually publish complete code. But now as we are in the middle of development , we are just required to upload any new files created which can be quite less in numbers (1 or 2 or maybe few). Now if we deploy with thunder , it publishes all files and then deploys complete code which takes good amount of time. Is there a way we can deploy only changed or new code files via sitefinity thunder or is there any other way with which we can only upload only the changed files? 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I use Beyond Compare 3 from scooter software to move files to our different Sitefinity environments.  I haven't used Sitefinity Thunder to deploy my sites before.  Also, you might want to post your question on the Sitefinity Devs group on Google+.  Below is the link.

https://plus.google.com/communities/101682685148530961591

Comment: using the beyond compare 3 tool, can i deploy to azure cloud services? also if yes then will this tool only deploy the changed or new files which is very important? thanks for the reply. i will check google forum as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy to do and Azure is not designed for this although many people have requested this feature. The one way to achieve it is to enable Remote Desktop for the cloud service and then by logging onto the server, you can then make some kind of connection to where your files are stored and copy them into the cloud service. However, it is always possible that the instance will be rebooted and even re-provisioned from fresh so I don't know if there are any guarantees that this is a safe way to do it.