# How to achieve Incremental deployment of Blob Files storage files to different environments of windows azure storage?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, tfs, storage, sitefinity

We are new to Windows azure and are developing a web application. In the beginning of the project , we have deployed complete code to different environments which actually publish complete code and uploaded blob objects to azure storage as we linked sitefinity to hold blob objects in azure storage . But now as we are in the middle of development , we are just required to upload any new blob files created which can be quite less in numbers (1 or 2 or maybe few).Now I would like to know best process to sync these blob files to different azure storage environments which is for each cloud service. So ideally we would like to update staging cloud service and staging storage first and then test there and then once no bugs are found, then will be required to update UAT and production storages as well with the changed or new blob objects.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Azure Storage Explorer](http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/) to manually upload/download blobs from storage accounts very easily. For one or two blobs, this would be an easy solution, otherwise you will need to write a tool that connects to the blob storage via an API and does the copying for you.